# Find if and when a Query was run?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, audit

I am trying to get to the root of a problem and need to see if and when a specific Delete Query was run on my MS SQL Server.
The command would have come from my .NET website.

My Server is Windows 2012 R2 running SQL 2014 Express.

The query would have run at some point in the last 3 weeks or so.

Comment: Do you have any audit functionality enabled on your SQL Server?

Comment: I am a novice at managing the DB. I do enough to make sure that it functions for the few websites that are using it. So, I imagine that all I have is whatever is built-in by default. I am willing to install or set up something more to at least find out in the future stuff like this. But I can't afford to spend a lot of money, as this is a small DB self-hosted for a few websites only Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In a database where [SQL Server Audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) was not previously configured you could try to [Read SQL Server Transaction Log Backups to Find When Transactions Occurred](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3555/read-sql-server-transaction-log-backups-to-find-when-transactions-occurred/) with the use of the undocumented function `fn_dump_dblog`.

For future situations where you need to audit a database I advise you to [Create a server audit and database audit specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/create-a-server-audit-and-database-audit-specification?view=sql-server-ver15).

---

Unfortunately, based on your comment

> all I have is whatever is built-in by default

I'd say you have no means to find the info you seek and the reason is that, by default, a new database you create on a SQL Server Express uses the [Simple Recovery Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#RMov), which doesn't allow taking log backups. Therefore, the function I mentioned will not help.

Comment: From what I have read Database Level Auditing is not available on 2014 Express Edition (Which is what is installed)

Comment: @Yoni, you're probably right, the [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2014](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/2014/getting-started/features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2014?view=sql-server-2014&preserve-view=true#Enterprise_security) shows you only have Basic Auditing available for the Express edition (not sure what those include). But you can still use the `fn_dump_dblog`. Do you have the log backups to search for the info you need?

Comment: Should I change my recovery model?

Comment: @Yoni that's an entirely new question and I'm afraid it's one way too wide to be answered in a comment. One last piece of advice: if you still don't have backups of your databases, create a routine of taking regular backups of them, or you might find yourself in a situation worse than the one you're in now. [Ola Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) has a free solution for that ;)

Comment: @Yoni, If you have the opportunity, upgrade your SQL Server to 2016 (13.x) SP1 or a newer version to be able to use audits. I just noticed this on the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15): "All editions of SQL Server support server level audits. All editions support database level audits beginning with SQL Server 2016 (13.x) SP1. Prior to that, database level auditing was limited to Enterprise, Developer, and Evaluation editions."